# Literate Programming with rust and org mode

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, literate-programming

So I am trying to use rust in org mode, and it works fine after installing **ob-rs** and **cargo-script**. But the problem is, I can't figure out how to use other crates(like [rand](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/)) from the source code blocks. I tried just converting the main project into a cargo one and tangle all the blocks to the main file, but well, I might as well use a normal rust project at that point. So is there a way to use external crates inside org mode blocks. It would be kinda difficult to use rust in org mode otherwise because a lot to basic functionality is defined in external crates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that we can use external crates with rust in org mode with [rustic](https://github.com/brotzeit/rustic). Here is the procedure to do that from the main README.

> ## Org-babel
>
> Blocks run asynchronously and a running babel process is indicated by
> a spinner in the mode-line. It's possible to use crates in babel
> blocks.
>
> Execute babel block with org-babel-execute-src-block
>
> ```
> #+BEGIN_SRC rustic :crates '((regex . 0.2))   extern crate regex;
>
>   use regex::Regex;
>
>   fn main() {
>       let re = Regex::new(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$").unwrap();
>       assert!(re.is_match("2014-01-01"));   }
> #+END_SRC
> ```
>
> Supported org babel parameters:
>
> Write to file :results file :file ~/babel-output
>
> Customization:
>
> ```
> rustic-babel-format-src-block format block after successful build
> rustic-babel-display-compilation-buffer display compilation buffer of babel process
> rustic-display-spinner turn off spinner in the mode-line
> ```

It is not perfect as using rustic as the src type means no syntax highlighting in github rendering of the org document. Also, we can't share fucntions between blocks but it is an open issue which can be found [here](https://github.com/brotzeit/rustic/issues/122), so hopefully we should get that ability at some point.